# Data passes in a particular time interval

Tags: javascript, loops, meteor, foreach, settimeout

The answer i needed is to come up with a particular interval . The code is

```
const myMap = new Map([
  [ "A", 1 ],
  [ "B", 2 ],
  [ "c", 3 ],
  [ "d", 4 ],
  [ "e", 5 ],
  [ "f", 6 ],
  [ "g", 7 ]
]);


myMap.forEach( (val, key) => 
     Meteor.setTimeout(test(),9000)
);

function test(){
   console.log("jajjjaja");
   console.log(Date());
}
```

And the Result is [image: Output]

My Time **interval is 9 Sec** ,But Result in all Same Second? How to get each result in Each 9 second

Comment: take setTimeout in your function.

Comment: ok. but same out outputs here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the setTimeout functions are all invoked together since every setTimeout is given to the process queue at the same time, after 9s pass they are picked by the event loop one by one but since all finished at the same time they gave the same Date() as the output, if you want you can keep a counter and setTimeout as 9*counter seconds that would solve your problem here is a running example

```
const myMap = new Map([
  [ "A", 1 ],
  [ "B", 2 ],
  [ "c", 3 ],
  [ "d", 4 ],
  [ "e", 5 ],
  [ "f", 6 ],
  [ "g", 7 ]
]);


myMap.forEach(function(key, value){
    test(key);
});

function test(key){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("jajjjaja");
        console.log(Date());
    },9000*key);
}
```